# Unable add overlayLayers to <l-layers-control/> in vue-leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, web-frontend

I have this code in vue using the vue-leaflet library:

```
<template>
  <l-map
  style="width: 100%; height: 100vh"
  :center="[22.841262817382812, -82.83554077148438]"
  :zoom="7"
  @ready="isReady"
  :crs="mapcrs"
  :options="{ attributionControl: false }"
>
  <l-control-layers></l-control-layers>
  <l-tile-layer
    v-for="layer in computedbaseLayers"
    :key="layer.name"
    :name="layer.name"
    :visible="layer.visible"
    :url="layer.url"
    :attribution="layer.attribution"
    layer-type="base"
  ></l-tile-layer>
  <l-control-attribution
    position="bottomright"
    prefix="Leaflet"
  ></l-control-attribution>
  <l-marker
    name="Current location"
    layer-type="overlay"
    v-if="userLocation"
    :lat-lng="userLocation"
  >
    <l-popup
      ><p><b>Your location is:</b></p>
      <p>Lat: {{ latlon[0] }}</p>
      <p>Lng: {{ latlon[1] }}</p></l-popup
    >
  </l-marker>
  <slot></slot>
</l-map>
</template>
```

With this function I get the map when is ready and add a WMS layer:

```
const mapReady = async (refmap) => {
  const wmsconf = mapProvider.getWMSService() as any;
  maplayerstore.setMap(refmap);

  var areas: any = new L.TileLayer.WMS(wmsconf.wms, {
    ...wmsconf.conf,
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
  }).addTo(refmap);
 .....
```

But I have a problem. The LControlLayer display on the screen the panel for choice the base map, but I'm unable to add the overlayLayers like the *areas* variable. The WMS display on the map, but I can't toggle it. How could I solve this?